# Bootstrap's javascript interfering with button dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's "split-button" dropdowns and had included the apparently required bootstrap javascript called bootstrap-button.js and for all my trying I couldn't get the darn thing to drop down. I then started removing JS files that might interfere and guess what? it was the bootstrap-button.js file that was the culprit! How does that make sense? The only way to have the boxes drop down is to NOT include the dropdown JS file?

Has anyone else seen this problem? Any suggestions on what to do or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you checked the JS console to look for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake which likely occurs because the **bootstrap.min.js**, which most people download, already includes all the plugins, and since the docs for the JavaScript plugins explicitly call for including the individual files, people unwittingly load the plugins they want twice.

Many of the plugins will exhibit behaviors similar to what you are describing if they get loaded twice into a page. The reason for this is that the plugins' event listeners are attached to the page in such a way as to allow two identical event listeners to be attached at the same time.  Hence what tends to happen on a double load is that when a click happens on a component, a call to a `show()` and then a call a `hide()` method (or `toggle()` x 2) will occur in sequence, neutralizing the expected outcome.

I think part of the reason why the direct downloads of the individual JavaScript plugins was removed from the documentation in 2.1 was in order to reduce the avenues which lead to this mistake. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have completely eliminated it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using bootstrap.min.js. I'm open to this kind of conflict still being at the heart of this though but it would be coming from another plugin in the wordpress environment.

Comment: In fact, I see now that the wordpress theme i'm using has "script.bootstrap.min.js" in it. Interesting, hadn't realised they were using it too albeit an older version. I guess there's no easy way to namespace these apart from one anther is there?

Comment: @ken Well that's an unexpected surprise! If this ([script.bootstrap.min.js](http://www.wpsubscribers.com/pagelines/script.bootstrap.min.js)) is the version in the theme, then it looks like the namespaces for the event listeners are identical to the current version, unfortunately. However, one option would be to disable the old listeners before the new ones load. Something like `$('body,html').off('click.dropdown');`.  But since there's a bunch of plugins, your best bet would be seeing if there's an updated version of the theme.  Otherwise you're going have more conflicts like this.

Comment: thanks for your help, hadn't thought of disabling at the JS level. I've put a request into the Theme developer whether they have a simple way of disabling the loading of this libraray (they didn't use to use it) and what dependencies the base theme has on it. I was thinking I could then "de-queue" the script on the PHP side and hopefully my newer version will meet all the dependencies of the Theme (which I'm hoping are small ... but who knows).